# Client and server: data filtering and sorting synchronization.

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, crud

I have a java client-server crud application. In client I open person table and I can set filter for example by city,age,sex. Besides I can add some sorting rule, for example sort by name,and after by age. These filtering and sorting rules are sent to server where they are passed to sql dao and used in sql code. So server returns DTO to client according to filtering and sorting rules. It's is important - it is server that implements these rules as client only passes these rules to server. Everything is easy and clear.

Now I create new Person in client application. Newly added person must be visible in table of persons. And now I came across a problem. How to add this person to table according to filtering and sorting rules. The only solution I see is to make client refresh all the data from the server according to the same rules. However it is obvious this is bad solution.

I am sure that this is common problem for crud application. What are possible solutions: patterns,algorithms,libs? What is the name of this problem (if it exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The broad category of the problem is layered architecture (an architectural pattern) and this question deals with where to run the domain logic of the system.

---

On client-server systems a decision needs to be made where the processing should occur. There are broadly three different options:

**1) Run everything on server**

This is often the simplest case. The great advantage is that everything is simple to upgrade and fix because it's in limited places. The downside is that the clients need to make a roundtrip to server even for the simplest functionality and this causes the user experience to suffer. From maintenance point of view this is the best option.

**2) Run everything on client**

The general arguments in favor of processing on the client is user interface responsiveness and disconnected operation. In this case the server acts only as the dumb datasource. Many times if you need to move some logic to the client it is best to move it all there - at least it is in one place then. However, keeping the clients in sync and avoiding compatibility errors brings challenges.

**3) Split the processing between client and server**

This option may have the deficiencies of both worlds. The main reason to do this is that there is only a small amount of domain logic that needs to run also on the client. The trick then is to isolate the common functionality into its own self-contained module that isn't dependent on any other part of the system. This way you can run the module on both the client and the server.

---

The simplest option would be to go with (1) where the client would send the new person data to the server and the server would return the updated, sorted and filtered person list to the client. Obviously this requires a server round-trip and may hurt the user experience.

The other option is go with (3) where you would duplicate the domain logic of the server on the client. The way forward then would be to isolate the person handling module so you can use it on both ends.